# How many permutations of an alphanumeric string of length 32

Tags: algorithm, permutation

Considering using the characters (elements) a-z and 0-9 how many different permutations are there when using a string of length 32?

The elements can be used more than once, but the results have to be unique (as is the case with a permutation).

I've looked at WolframAlpha however that doesn't state how many 'elements' that would be used, it only considers the length.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [math.se], as opposed to a specific programming problem.

Comment: You're right, but as I am working on a web based project I thought about posting it here as I didn't want a mathematical explanation, just a figure so I can work out how big I need the column length of my database to be. I didn't specify a language to be used as it doesn't matter. Additionally others might find this useful when creating unique IDs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have 32 positions for either 10 different digits or 26 characters. In each position either goes a character or a digit so you have 36 possibilities. This leave us with:

```
36*36*36...*36 (32 times)
= 36^32
= 63340286662973277706162286946811886609896461828096 # (thanks Python ;) )
```

Comment: Thank you, it is what I thought, but I wasn't sure whether or not it was 36*35*34*33....

Comment: You're welcome. That is when you can't repeat the last element you've used in the next position.

Comment: It would be 36*35*34*33... if you were only allowed to have non-repetitive characters.

Comment: @Paulo Bu, why next position ? It should be all next positions.

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan Sorry I didn't explain myself right. I mean exactly what you said :) non-repetitive characters.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is `(26+10)^32` = 6.3340287e+49

Comment: Thank you, your answer was correct too.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on if you're allowed to have replacement or not.

If you are allowed replacement, you have 36 possibilities for each character position = 36^32.

If you're not allowed replacement, you have 36 for the first, 35 for the second, etc, until you run out of character positions.  That's 36! / 4!, also written as [36 **P** 32](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=36P32).